# What is a good api to sql from visual c++

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio

I want to do simple stuff like adding entries and reading entries by index.  What libraries are there and which ones are the best?

Comment: What is your target database?

Comment: I am building it as a sql db, by adding entries again and again

Comment: Yes, but which SQL database?  There are several, and the database you're using will dictate the API you use.  SQL Server, Oracle, Access, MySQL... something else?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.  I am not sure.  Maybe you should tell me which one to use.  I am using visual c++ and I want a free database.  which one should I use?

Comment: My DB will contain just a lot of questions and answers.  maybe 200-500 questions and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) would be a good simple SQL database engine, with a [simple embedded C++ interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

[SQLAPI++](http://www.sqlapi.com/) would be a good choice for many commercial SQL databases (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Sybase, Informix, InterBase, SQLBase, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite and ODBC)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use Microsoft's SQL Server Compact Edition. It is free, and has Visual Studio integration.

You can download it and find out more at the following link:
[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142)

Comment: Which api would go well with it?

Comment: Just start with the [Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173994(v=SQL.100).aspx). It has information on how to build applications using it. When you have more specific questions, come back and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

If you not worried about HUGE concurrency then use SQLite (www.sqlite.org).  Download the aggregated version and you only have 2 files: sqlite3.h and sqlite3.c.  It's REALLY easy to use and requires no server set up or configuration.

Comment: What about the files sqlite3ext.h and shell.c are they not important?  Can I omit them?

Comment: shell.c is a simple command line executable that allows you to enter SQL comments.  You do not need this.  And I am not sure what sqlite3ext.h is (if I was to guess is for the app developer to add extensions to sqlite3) but I have never used it.